# Sort a table in golang

Tags: sorting, go

I have table in golang. I need to sort it based on a particular column. Can someone help me to proceed?

```
table := ui.Table([]string{"SI No","Name","ID","status","submitted-at"})
strs := dat["resources"].([]interface{})
var ln int = 20
i:=0
for i < ln {
    table.Add(strconv.Itoa(i+1), metadataName , metadataID, metadataStatus, metadataSubmittedAt)
    i = i + 1
}
```

Comment: Can you auctually provide the data structure of what you want to be sorted?

Comment: sort.Sort or sort.Slice.

Comment: It is a table as a whole that I wanted to sort as shown above in the code.

Comment: We don't know what type `ui.Table` has. For all we know, it's from a library that already has a `SortByColumn` method. If you want help, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) on the standard library includes an [interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) that if you implement it for any type then it can be sorted using the `sort.Sort()` function.

Even if the `ui.Table` object is from a package or library you can't modify, you can always declare a new type using `ui.Table` as it's base and implement the `sort.Interface` yourself, something like:

```
type myTable ui.Table

func (m myTable) Len() int           { return len(m) }
func (m myTable) Swap(i, j int)      { m[i], m[j] = m[j], m[i] }
func (m myTable) Less(i, j int) bool { return m[i].col() < m[j].col() }
```

Or you know some implementation that makes sense for the Table type. Here I'm assuming that your rows have a function `col()` that returns the value of the column you are using to sort for that row and that `Table` is a slice of rows which is probably not the case.

I wish I could help more but it's not possible to help you with any implementation details if you don't give any details about `ui.Table`.